# Tiny dock icon bug

Tags: dock, icon

every time I wake up my Macbook pro 2021 M1Pro, few icons in the dock looks wired. Please see the attached picture for this bug.[image] I have tried many steps such as restarting, erasing everything then downloading the macOS system and etc. But still can't fix it!!!!! Anyone have the same issue or know how to fix it is appreciated!!!

Comment: I also tried 'killall Dock' command, only works for a few hours or days. The bug will still appear in days.

Comment: Do you have any software which interferes with the menubar or the interface in any way? Erasing everything (and then putting everything back) is rarely a fix.

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I have interference or bugs on the menubar as well. However, all the software I have are very common and widely used. I am not sure if any one of them will cause interference...

Comment: If you're not sure now, you will only be sure if you test with each one unlaunched. I'm talking about software which is designed to alter the menubar, or other part of the user interface. Even widely used software has bugs. Are you on the latest versions? Can you show us the other problems?

Comment: @benwiggy I am on the latest versions. My bugs exist for many the versions, because it have been existing for a long time. For the other problem, I need a video file to show it as it only happens when I switch the screens..But I am not sure if the exchange allows a video link..

Comment: I've not seen any other report of a similar bug, so it's almost certainly a problem with your computer, caused by the combination of software and settings that you have. You can test a brand new user account, and see if that has the problem. If it doesn't then that confirms that it is something in your original user account, e.g. an app or background process that is configured to run.